# How can I use the recovery console to start a session step by step?

Tags: 10.10, login-screen, gdm, recovery-mode

If you select "Recovery Console" at the GDM login screen, you are presented with a terminal screen in the top corner of the screen and the usual GDM background.

I'm trying to diagnose a problem which occurs straight after login where the machine hangs.

Which commands should I run from here and in what order to get myself into the state I would normally be in had I logged in the normal way?

Thanks

Comment: Difficult to do.  You would have to go through the steps in /etc/init/gdm.conf and then launch gdm-binary.  But if your machine hangs, how do you hope to diagnose anything?

Comment: It hangs quite late in the login process so I would like to see which step is causing the hang, and then use that to try and solve it.

Comment: Hm, gdm is a binary prgram that's the parent process of the rest of your session.  I don't think it's feasible to believe you can easily reproduce steps (AFAIK).  As an alternative, does it completely hang or can you access the console with `CRTL+ALT+F1`? If you can do that or you reboot and access a terminal you can have a look at `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: I've already had a look at .xsession-errors and nothing looked particularly unusual. I solved the problem by erasing the user and re-creating it, but I'm sure the problem will resurface in the future.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't a problem with xorg at all but a problem with compiz, hence it not showing obviously in any of the xorg logs. Deleting the .compiz folder and restaring X seemed to fix it.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).